# Qemu-system-x86_64 pegging the processor

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I have a Mid 2015 MBP that I use for developing both Android and iOS apps.  I have been having a lot of issues with the Android emulator using way too much processor.  Sometimes it's using 120% - 130%.  My system fans run full blast the entire time I'm trying to work with it and it's gotten to the point where I really just don't want to work on the code anymore because of the effects on the computer.

I have scoured the internet looking for solutions.  The one that I came across that seemed to work for a while was editing the config.ini for the emulator and updating the following lines:

```
hw.audioInput=no

hw.audioOutput=no

hw.cpu.ncore=1

hw.gps=no
```

This seemed to work and my processor dropped to 8% - 15% and my computer stopped overheating.  After a while, this stopped working.  I've tried everything that I can think of.  I've restarted the emulator, stopped and started the emulator, and even killed and recreated the emulator.  Nothing has worked.

This seems like a big enough issue that I see all kinds of posts around for it.  Has there ever been a solution that works all the time?  I've updated Android Studio to the latest version.  I am on OS Catalina right now.  I cannot think of anything else to do.